# Why is node.js not generating an email with guerrillamail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I am writing code that creates an email address with guerrillamail.
But, the code I created below:

```
var request = require('request');    
var jar = request.jar();
    request({
        uri: 'http://api.guerrillamail.com/ajax.php',
        method: 'GET',
        proxy: proxy,
        jar: jar,
        form: {
            "f": "get_email_address"
        }
    }, function(e, response, b) {
       console.log(b);
    });
```

Only logs :

> ERR_INVALID_REQ

In body when I log it. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably need a POST request not GET try changing the method